# What is the reason file not uploaded in Instragram via python code

Tags: instagram, python-3.8

I have tried to upload the video file in MacOS using `python3` but no luck every time it shows uploaded but I do not see the video file in my Instagram account. Could you please provide reason for the same? where is the file now?

Code:

```py
from instabot import *
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username = "xx", password="xx")
bot.upload_video("IMG_6517.m4v",caption ="First Video install directly from myPc without using Insta UI")
```

Result:

> 2020-06-06 14:24:31,763 - INFO - Started uploading
> '/Users/samirthantharate/Desktop/IMG_6517.m4v'
> 2020-06-06 14:24:31,763 - INFO - Started uploading
> '/Users/samirthantharate/Desktop/IMG_6517.m4v'
> Analizing `/Users/samirthantharate/Desktop/IMG_6517.m4v`
> FOUND w:720, h:1280, rotation=0, ratio=0.5625
> Vertical video
> Cropping video
> 2020-06-06 14:25:06,836 - INFO - Video
> '/Users/samirthantharate/Desktop/IMG_6517.m4v' uploaded
> 2020-06-06 14:25:06,836 - INFO - Video
> '/Users/samirthantharate/Desktop/IMG_6517.m4v' uploaded
> {'upload_id': '1591433671764', 'device_timestamp': '1591433671764'}

Comment: Looking at the code of upload_video, you should probably troubleshoot two extra functions that are called underneath: configure_video and resise_video
https://github.com/ohld/igbot/blob/master/instabot/api/api_video.py#L88
Moreover, I don't see the log message of the thumbnail and you haven't passed it as parameter which would lead me to think that the issue is on the resize

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in the python script nor the library, the real issue is the soft ban imposed upon your account by Instagram. Instagram has been actively monitoring such activities and imposing such soft bans stealthily. I suggest you try after 5-10 days, I can make sure that the script would start working.

Such issues have been reported already, do see those issues over here:
https://github.com/ohld/igbot/issues/1211
https://github.com/ohld/igbot/issues/1194

*Also, the following python script is now detectable by Instagram as specified by the author in Readme https://github.com/ohld/igbot/blob/master/OLD_README.md*

Comment: I'm haven't faced such issues, my script works just fine, my last successful post was about 8 minutes ago.

Comment: Depends, I had to face the softban a few months back and since then I have been trying different tools. I have been using https://profilebud.com for quite a few time which is good for my use-case, not sure if it has upload capability.

Comment: but, in case of *softban*, the script should not be able to successfully login and should not be able to upload media (*like in the question it shows media is uploaded but actually hasn't been uploaded*) right?